# Android Studio compiler warning source

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1

When building my app in Android Studio (3.1), I'm getting a warning:

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.

I don't use `compile` in any of my dependencies. How can I tell which line in `build.gradle` produces this warning?

[image]

Comment: This warning is not for your project may be for another third party library you are using.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + f` -> `compile`. Any results found?

Comment: @Oxalihn how can I tell the difference between my warnings and third party?

Comment: @Michael no results.